# Scrollview in a HorizontalScrollView and that in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview

I want to make a week view that is both horizontally and vertically scroll able. once it reaches the horizontal end of the view it should change the page of the viewPager.
So far, I have added a ScrollView in a HorizontalScrollView and inflated the Weekview in a viewpage, and that's where the problem occurs, nor the Horizontal scrollView works correctly, neither the view pager.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id ="@+id/week_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Monday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Tuesday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Wednesday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Thursday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Friday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Saturday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Sunday"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:id ="@+id/timing_list"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timingLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.fibodo.widget.HorizontalScrolllView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrolllView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/week_list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/timing_list"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <com.fibodo.widget.ScrolllView
            android:id="@+id/scrolllView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mondaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tuesdaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/wednesdaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/thursdaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fridaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/saturdaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sundaylayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.fibodo.widget.ScrolllView>
    </com.fibodo.widget.HorizontalScrolllView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to inflate this layout in viewpager

Comment: put your xml file here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra layout of the viewpager item added.. Viewpager is android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp" android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"